# Error when trying to turn infix to postfix

Tags: python

```
class Caculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def convert(self, infix):
        # use a stack to covert infix to postfix
        self.stack.clear()
        postfix = []

        for c in infix:
            if c == '(':
                self.stack.append(c)
            elif c == ')':
                if not self.stack:
                    while (self.stack and self.stack[-1]) != '(':
                        poped_char = self.stack.pop()
                        postfix.append(poped_char)
            elif c == '+' or c == '-':
                if not self.stack:
                    while (self.stack and self.stack[-1]) == '+' or (self.stack and self.stack[-1]) == '-':
                        poped_char = self.stack.pop()
                        postfix.append(poped_char)
            elif c == '/' or c == '*':
                if not self.stack:
                    while (self.stack and self.stack[-1]) == '/' or (self.stack and self.stack[-1]) == '*':
                        poped_char = self.stack.pop()
                        postfix.append(poped_char)
            else:
                self.stack.append(c)

        while len(self.stack) != 0:
            poped_char = self.stack.pop()
            postfix.append(poped_char)

        return postfix
```

When I try to input an infix it throws an error, but I think the list should still have the operand because all I am doing in the code is checking what the variable is. I'm not sure if it is because I made the stack an object, but any help would be greatly appreciated. I added the log from me trying the program.

Edit: I changed the not equal to 0 to if.not self.stack which made the code work but the output doesn't have the operator.

```
Please enter a postfix: 1+2
['2', '1']
```

Comment: `while (self.stack and self.stack[-1]) == '/' or '*':` doesn't do what you expect. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al

Comment: Now `while (self.stack and self.stack[-1]) != '(':` is the problem. When `self.stack` is an empty list, `(self.stack and self.stack[-1])` is also an empty list, so it's not equal to `(`.

Comment: Right.  In both cases, the problem is the way you have used parentheses.

Comment: Also, your `if not self.stack:` is backwards.  You want `if self.stack`.  Otherwise, the `while` never runs, because `self.stack` is empty.  However, that's not the only issue here.  The logic is flawed.  You're leaving the parens in there; postfix should have no parens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two stacks -- one to hold the numbers/operands you haven't already processed, and one to hold the pending operators.  When you find a closed paren `)`, you have to pop an operator and two operands until you find the open paren.  THEN, when you get a '+' or '-', you have to handle any pending multiplies, since they have a higher priority.

```
class Calculator:
    def convert(self, infix):
        numbers = []
        stack = []
        postfix = []

        def unroll():
            op = stack.pop()
            n2 = numbers.pop()
            n1 = numbers.pop()
            if n2:
                postfix.extend([n1,n2,op])
            else:
                postfix.extend([n1,op])
            numbers.append(None)

        for c in infix:
            if c == '(':
                stack.append(c)
            elif c == ')':
                while stack and stack[-1] != '(':
                    unroll()
                stack.pop()
            elif c in '+-':
                while stack and stack[-1] in '*/':
                    unroll()
                stack.append(c)
            elif c in '*/':
                stack.append(c)
            else:
                numbers.append(c)

        print(numbers,stack)
        while stack:
            unroll()

        return postfix

x = Calculator()
print(x.convert('9 + 123 * ( 456 + 789 + 321 )'.split()))
```

Output:

```
['789', '321', '+', '456', '+', '123', '*', '9', '+']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Caculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def convert(self, infix):
        self.stack.clear()
        postfix = []

        for c in infix:
            if c == '(':
                self.stack.append(c)
            elif c == ')':
                while (self.stack and self.stack[-1]) != '(':
                    poped_char = self.stack.pop()
                    postfix.append(poped_char)
                self.stack.pop()
            elif c == '+' or c == '-':
                while (self.stack and self.stack[-1] in ('+', '-', '*', '/')):
                    poped_char = self.stack.pop()
                    postfix.append(poped_char)
                self.stack.append(c)
            elif c == '/' or c == '*':
                while (self.stack and self.stack[-1] in ('*', '/')):
                    poped_char = self.stack.pop()
                    postfix.append(poped_char)
                self.stack.append(c)
            else:
                postfix.append(c)

        while self.stack:
            poped_char = self.stack.pop()
            postfix.append(poped_char)

        return postfix
```

There are few changes in the code.

```
while (self.stack and self.stack[-1]) == '+'
```

does not work as this is a boolean and is compared with a string.

```
if not self.stack:
```

is not needed as this is is already present inside while loop condition. Stack must be updated after the end of while loop.